# Weird error using encrypt module with migrate and migrate_d2d modules

Tags: migrations

I'm having a weird message pop up when I go to the migrate group I'm trying to port content over from.

The message I get is :

> Failed to decrypt argument *source_database*

I have no idea what source_database is and what argument it's trying to decrypt.

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got a line number or anything?

Comment: @cilefen - unfortunately I do not. It's just a message that pops up every now and then. It seems to have gone away as I recreated the migrate_d2d database migration plan.